# Internal energy: $\Delta E_{\text{int}}=\mathcal K+\mathcal U \iff \Delta E_{\text{int}}=Q-L$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

In thermodynamics textbook of my students of an high school there is not an explanation of the equality

$$\Delta E_{\text{int}}=\mathcal K+\mathcal U \iff \Delta E_{\text{int}}=Q-L \tag 1$$
with the $\mathcal K$ (kinetic energy) and $\mathcal U$ (potential energy)

I have explained only the
$$\Delta E_{\text{int}}=Q-L $$

with the signs of the work $L$ and the heat $Q$ done on the system or out the system.

How can I explain simply the $(1)$?

Comment: It  is surely the *total* internal energy  that is given by $E_{\int}= {\mathcal K}+{\mathcal V}$,
 and not the *change* in the internal energy.

Comment: @mikestone Hi, hence I have misunderstood the concept of internal energy. Can you explain better your comment please (easily) with an answer?

Comment: The internal energy is the sum of the kinetic energy and the potential energy. I don't see what you can be  puzzled about , so I can't explain any better. See Bob D's modified answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first equation

$$\Delta E_{int}=K+U$$

$K$ and $U$ are the *changes* in internal kinetic and potential energy, respectively, of the system at the molecular (microscopic) level. It would be better if the book presented as $\Delta K$ and $\Delta U$. Or, alternatively, change $\Delta E_{int}$ to $E_{int}$.

The internal kinetic energy is the sum of the translational, rotational and vibrational molecular kinetic energies, as applicable, of the molecules. The internal potential energy is that associated with the relative positions of the molecules and the intermolecular forces between the molecules.

In the second equation

$$\Delta E_{int}=Q-L$$

$Q$ is energy transfer to/from the system in the form of heat and is positive when heat is transferred to the system. $L$ is energy transfer in the form of work done by/on the system and is positive when work is done by the system.

Putting them together, the total change in the sum of the internal microscopic kinetic and potential energies of the system  (first equation) equals the net transfer of energy to/from the system in the form of heat and/or work (second equation).

> Hence are there two differents equivalent explanations that implies to
> have the same concept?

The first equation describes the nature of the components of change in internal energy. The second equation describes how those components change, i.e., energy transfer in the form of heat and/or work. –

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess there should be a delta in front of the K+U?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yeah, or define K and U as the change in kinetic energy and potential energy. I revised my answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1: Hence are there two differents equivalent explanations that implies to have the same concept? Starting from K+U hence I not found Q-L!

Comment: @Sebastiano See Chet's comment and my revision. The first equation describes the nature of the components of change in internal energy. The second equation describes how those components change, i.e., energy transfer in the form of heat and/or work.

Comment: I have seen, before, the comment of @ChetMiller :-). Can you put your last comment into your answer, please. Thus I not see the comment. I prefer to have all into in the answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sure, will do.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyyyyyy much.